# how to plot with result data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a result data frame, and I want to plot a bar graph with this data.
Here's the data:

```
df<-data.frame(
  chq=c("Eb","Pb","Sb","En","Bn"),
  ph.mean=c("9.8","8.0","7.9","13.9","10.0"),
  ph.sd=c("3.3","4.2","3.3","6.3","4.2"),
  hc.mean=c("6.6","7.4","6.1","11.1","8.3"),
  hc.sd=c("1.3","2.6","2.6","3.4","1.5"),
  p.val=c("0.001","0.120","0.098","0.021","0.054")
)
```

Maybe it need to convert wide data to long data, I tried, but I have a problem with data conversion.

```
df.long <- gather(df, key = "group", value = "mean",
                    `phm`, `hcm`)
```

chq means five Categorical variables, ph and pc are two groups.I want to draw a bar graph with error bars.

```
ggplot(df.long,aes(chq,mean,fill=group))+
  geom_bar()+
  geom_errorbar()
```

like this
[image]

My confusion is that there is only one value for each group that can be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to reshape your data. The easiest way is probably using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. For example

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=ph.mean:hc.sd, names_pattern="(ph|hc).(mean|sd)", names_to=c("cond",".value")) %>% 
  mutate(across(mean:sd, as.numeric)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(chq, fill=cond) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position="dodge") + 
  geom_col(aes(y=mean), position="dodge")
```

The `pivot_longer` will reshape your data to something more like

```
   chq   p.val cond   mean    sd
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Eb    0.001 ph      9.8   3.3
 2 Eb    0.001 hc      6.6   1.3
 3 Pb    0.120 ph      8     4.2
```

so each condition is on it's own row with a mean and sd column.

Then we just use ggplot to plot the data. Not sure how you want to define your error bars but here I just added +1 SD.

[image]